# Google Cloud Storage - JAVA REST API - Getting SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using jersey-client to make REST Call . I am getting SignatureDoesNotMatch error in response. 
I was trying to List down Bucket names using GET Service , also tried to list Bucket object using GET Bucket method.
here is my sample code.

Any hint or solution ?

```java
public class restSample {

    private static final String HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA1";
    private static final String PROJECT_ID = "10XXXXXXXX478";

    public static String Base64Encoding()
            throws java.security.SignatureException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

          String access_id = "GOOGBAXXXXXXXXXXBI";
          String secret_key = URLEncoder.encode("pWTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXRo85T+XXXXXXXXX3O","UTF-8");
          String bucket = "bucket_name";

          String version_header = "x-goog-api-version:1";
          String project_header = "x-goog-project-id:"+PROJECT_ID;
          String canonicalizedResources = "/"+bucket+"/";

          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
          long expiration = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

         String stringToSign = URLEncoder.encode("GET\n\n\n"+expiration+"\n"+version_header+"\n"+project_header+"\n"+canonicalizedResources,"UTF-8");
         //String stringToSign = URLEncoder.encode("GET\n\n\n"+getdate()+"\n"+version_header+"\n"+project_header+"\n"+canonicalizedResources,"UTF-8");
         String authSignature="";
        try {

            SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(secret_key.getBytes(),HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);

            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
            mac.init(signingKey);

            // compute the hmac on input data bytes
            byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(stringToSign.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            // base64-encode the hmac
            authSignature = new String(Base64.encode(rawHmac));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SignatureException("Failed to generate HMAC : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        authSignature = (access_id +":"+ authSignature);
        return  authSignature;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);

        String authSignature = null;
        try {
            authSignature = "GOOG1 "+ Base64Encoding();
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI());
        ClientResponse response = service.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .header("Authorization",authSignature)
                .header("Date", getdate())
                .header("Content-Length", "0")
                .header("x-goog-api-version", "1")
                .header("x-goog-project-id", PROJECT_ID)
                .get(ClientResponse.class);

        System.out.println(response.getClientResponseStatus().getFamily());
        System.out.println("response1 :: " + response.getEntity(String.class));

    }

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        String url = "https://bucket_name.storage.googleapis.com";
        return UriBuilder.fromUri(url).build();
    }
    private static String getdate(){
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z ", new Locale("US"));
         Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(new SimpleTimeZone(0, "GMT"));

         format.setCalendar(cal);
         return format.format(new Date());
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the string you are signing matches the expected string to sign. Google cloud storage returns the expected string to sign in the HTTP response if authentication fails.

In your particular example it looks like you are adding both the `version_header` and `project_header` into the string to sign. These are not in the list of `CanonicalHeaders` nor `CanonicalExtensionHeaders`, so you are signing a different string than the server.

You can review the list here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference/v1/developer-guidev1#authentication